# Should I set object to nill in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avaudioplayer

I am reading someone's code. He set `AVAudioPlayer` to nil after user clicking a button to stop the audio from playing. I am wondering should we set object to nil after we don't need it anymore? Or should we set `AVAudioPlayer` to nil after we are trying to stop playing the audio?

Answer (score 3):

Usually, this is not needed but there are exceptions. When you have a local variable, you almost never need to set it to `nil` because when it goes out of scope, it will be destroyed anyway.

When you have a variable on instance scope (a property), it's more difficult because you often want to release the memory while the instance is still being used (for example, a property in a controller). In this case, setting to `nil` is completely correct because you have no other way to remove the object from memory.

The fact that it's a `AVAudioPlayer` instance shouldn't be relevant although the player usually takes a big chunk of memory so it's good to watch for its instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a strong member variable, you may be able to free a significant amount of resources earlier on by deliberately disposing of objects by setting them to nil when no longer required. The benefit will depend on the specific type of object in question.